# Confirm password and email field in spring MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, spring, passwords

For our project I've build a registration form with Spring MVC.
However one of the requirements was that the user have to confirm her/his email and password.
I created 2 fields, email and email (confirm) and password, password (confirm).
When i want to check if email equals email (confirm) and password equals password (confirm).
Is it necessary to add the confirm field to my model? I'm not sure if its a good idea to add the confirm field to my model since its not relevant information.

Maybe you got any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think, that most convenient method would be to add these properties to your ViewModel, but ViewModel is not necessarily 100% must correspond to your model. For example, database table users doesn't have password_confirm column, also confirm password isn't used in your data entities (or Model), but in View (UI) you use this data field, so ViewModel has this property.

Comment: BTW, you can add javascript checking - client side validation, but You must do not forget, that some clients disables javascript. So, validate params also server side unless you don't care about javascript less browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Sandar,

There is no need to provide any extra fields at Model or Controller, just create your fields at the View part only.

Create four input tags like :

```
<form.... onsubmit="return checkConfirmFields();>

<input type="text" name="email"/>
<input type="text" name="confirmEmail"/>
<input type="password" name="pass"/>
<input type="password" name="confirmPass"/>
<input type="submit" value="Register"/>

</form>
```

Now before submitting your form call one javascript function, for e.g. checkConfirmFields in above example and write simple logic to compare your email, password with confirm fields, and accordingly return true or false.

Hopefully you must have basic idea of javascript as you are using Spring MVC.

Comment: +1 Nice approach, though if you want your validation error messages for confirmation violations to look like other validation error messages then there's an advantage to including the confirm fields in a DTO at least.

Comment: @Willie : agreed.. But may be error messages in whole project is wrap-up with div class="errorMessage", so that's how we can just assign class to error messages while displaying it from javascript too...

Comment: We're also using javascript validation, but its better to use serverside validation aswell. When a user doesnt have javascript enabled he can submit the form without any validation.